# Convert C++ OpenCv code using makePtr to C# with OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I am attempting to convert some C++ OpenCV code (using OpenCV 4.5.3) to C# (.NET 7.0) and OpenCvSharp.  Mostly it seems pretty easy and straightforward, but I have hit a snag with one block of code that uses solver and a function called `cv::MakePtr`.   This is the C++ code that I'm having trouble converting

```
void optLSQNonLinear(const cv::Mat& src, const std::vector<cv::Mat>& dsts,
                        int sizeH, int maxIter, double epsx, double epsf,
                        cv::Mat& parameters, cv::Point margin, 
                        bool selectPixels, cv::Point grid)
{
    cv::Mat _dsts;
    cv::vconcat(dsts, _dsts);

    cv::Ptr<LSQNonLinearCb>      callback = cv::makePtr<LSQNonLinearCb>(src, _dsts, sizeH, margin, selectPixels, grid);
    cv::Ptr<LSQNonLinear> solver = cv::makePtr<LSQNonLinear>(callback, maxIter, epsx, epsf);

    solver->run(parameters);
}
```

The solver class derives from a standard OpenCV class called `LMSolver`

```
class LSQNonLinearCb : public cv::LMSolver::Callback
```

I want to be able to duplicate this in C# but I see no equivalent of `cv::makePtr` or the `cv::LMSolver` class in OpenCvSharp.  I've even downloaded the latest OpenCvSharp repo and and I don't see anything.

I have very little experience with Open CV but many years of experience in both C++ and C# and interop between the two.

Is it possible to translate this into C# and OpenCvSharp?

Comment: there is no equivalent. an equivalent is neither desired nor possible. this ugliness is a consequence of C++. simply drop that stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that option.     I have to replicate in C# whatever this thing does.  I have no need to do it exactly the same way but I have to achieve whatever task this bit of code was trying accomplish.  There appears to be an entire "Solver" architecture there and clearly my C++ uses it.  Is there some alternate approach in .NET to doing what "Solver" does in the unmanaged version?

Comment: you misunderstood me. that thing is a "smart pointer". please learn what a "smart pointer" is in C++, and why that makes no sense in other languages.

Comment: I have been coding in C++ every single day of my professional career for over 30 years.  So I am quite familiar with smart pointers, thanks.  I have also been writing C# for over a decade.  And have been writing interop code between the two.  What I am trying to understand is how to replicate what this C++ code does in C#.  It appears to be some generic way to create an algorithm and plug it into Open CV in some way.  I want to know what the OpenCvSharp equivalent is.

Comment: from your confident response I gather that you *don't* have a problem with `cv::makePtr` and `cv::Ptr`. -- your subclass may give you trouble; I don't know how opencvsharp may support this. just try subclassing it in C#. -- https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/1634 may I suggest that you edit that to add backticks around the code, so stuff inside of < and > shows up? it does not when it's formatted as regular text.

Comment: Oops.  Must have accidentally deleted the opening ticks the last time I edited.  Fixed now, thanks.   As far as `cv::MakePtr` goes, I don't understand why OpenCv wants you to call its own function to create a new instance of the routine in the first place.  I assume it is to some way to somehow "plug it in" to the framework but my ignorance of Open CV is showing there.  I don't see any type of analagous creator method in OpenCvSharp.   So, assuming I find a way to create the LMSolver derivative,  do I just `new` it in C#?